# Removing hash from URL of Angular app is not working within docker container

Tags: angular, docker, hash

I am facing one issue after removing `hash` from URL of one of my angular app which running through docker. I am explaining my code below.

`src/app/app-routing.module.ts::`

```
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)  // removed { useHash: true }
]
```

So after removing `{ useHash: true }` now no hash is coming with `URL` but issue is when I am refreshing the page its giving `404` error. My angular application is running inside docker container and I am using `ubuntu:20.04` server for docker like below.

`Dockerfile::`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="a@gmail.com"
LABEL build_date="2021-09-17"

RUN apt-get update

# SET TZ
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN echo 'Asia/Kolkata' > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
...................................
...................................
```

Here I need after removing the `#` also when user will refresh the page the same page will appear again. Please help me to resolve this issue.